# get Multiple contacts from phone-book imported at a time to the app

Tags: android, android-contacts

I was able to import the contact that the user clicked, to my app. But I was having some hundreds of contacts in the phone-book. How should I let the user to pick at a time say some 50 contacts or may the selected contacts?

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html

and according to me.. you can use a kind of if or while loop for 50 count where you are calling the function to import contact.

That should help you limit the contact pickup for a kind.

Hope that helps. But you should surely try Support library of android it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop for 50 contacts or whatever number of contacts you want. Or you can filter it out contacts according to fields.